# A php redirect in my root is breaking the ability to browse a particular subfolder on my website

Tags: php, redirect

I recently decided to redirect my main website to my photography section, to make the photography section effectively the main website.  I therefore have the following in my index.php file in the root...

```
<?php Header( "Location: http://notails.com/photography" );  ?>
```

The odd thing is, if I try to browse to http://notails.com/photography/admin which is a password protected folder, I get redirected to http://notails.com/photography.   If I go to the index.php file in the root and comment out that line,  then try to browse to the admin page I am able to.   I don't understand why a bit of PHP in a file in one folder is redirecting me from another folder!    Any ideas?

As an aside,  I'd be happy for someone to tell me how to do this redirect in my htaccess file instead of in the index.php file.  I looked into it but I could find instructions on lots of things *except* this specific thing (redirect from the 'root' to a subfolder of the site)

Comment: A parent page couldn't possibly affect a file in a subdirectory unless it's being included/required somehow by that subdirectory page. Of if you have some other form of url rewriting occuring outside of php (eg. mod_rewrite).

Comment: Where does the system redirects after successful authentication?

Comment: Do you have anything in your htaccess file already?

Comment: Yes I have quite a few things in my htaccess file.  Some of it is wordpress stuff.  Some of it is 'friendly url' stuff I did.   After authentication the page is supposed to open 'index.php' in the 'admin' folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a number of solutions for redirecting a website.

The simplest way is to modify your .htaccess file which is in the root directory (i.e., public_html or something similar; wherever your current index.php or .html) file is.

(Note: when using index.php, the index.html has to be renamed or removed).

(add the following to the bottom of your .htaccess file...I say add instead of modify, just in case you aren't familiar with the contents and not sure what to change).

Solution: (last line of .htaccess)

> RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://yourdomain/yoursubdirectory/index.php

Regarding Access:
It is not clear to me how you are "browsing to admin". Is it being done within your website's pages (via some display of your site's directory structure)?

In general, make sure that the "/yourdomain/yoursubdirectory/index.php" is not setting and using a specific variable for the root directory and then appending "photography/admin" to it. 
If this is the case...you are now ending up with "/yourdomain/yoursubdirectory/yoursubdirectory/admin" which doesn't exist.

You may only need to correct that reference within your "/photography/index.php" file.

Hope something here helps.

J.
http://omki.us